# Add A New Item to React State from outside Entry Point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two buttons that have the same class and different ids. I would like a new item to be added to the cart when the button is clicked.

```
<body>
    <div id="account"></div>
    <button class="add-to-cart" id="1234">
        Add to cart
    </button>
    <button class="add-to-cart" id="1534">
        Add to cart 2
    </button>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

and the state management part of the react component looks like

```
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart')

        addToCartButtons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', e => {
                setCart(() => [...cart, button.id])
            })
        })
    }, [])
```

Any time the buttons are clicked, a new array is formed containing only a new value instead of spreading out the previous values of the cart and adding the new value.

Comment: Why do you render the buttons outside the React app?

Comment: @JMadeline because I want react to handle only the cart section of the application and have detailed pages for the e-commerce products in vanilla js

Answer (score 2):

From your code

```js
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart')

    addToCartButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', e => {
            setCart(() => [...cart, button.id])
        })
    })
}, [])
```

You can see that `cart` in `setCart(() => [...cart, button.id])` is always be the initial cart because there is no cart in dependency list of `useEffect`.

And then, you just want to use `componentDidMount` so you cannot add cart to the dependency list.

Try using `cart` variable via reference

For example

```js
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

const cartRef = useRef() // <--- import {useRef} from 'react'
cartRef.current = cart

useEffect(() => {
    const addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart')
    addToCartButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const currentCart = cartRef.current // <--- read cart variable using reference
            setCart(() => [...currentCart, button.id])
        })
    })
}, [])
```

Comment: Adding cart to the dependency array solved the issue, thank you so much!

Comment: If you add `cart` to the dependency array, you will perform `addEventListener` when you use function `setCart` which should be a bug for your system.

Comment: Oh alright, so the other solution is preferred and why? `addEventListener` is already listening to click events once the component is rendered.

Comment: useEffect will trigger input function if some data in the dependency list is changed, and addEventListener can use as many times as you want to handle the event with more event listeners. 
In conclusion, setCart will change the value of cart.
When cart value is changed, the function in useEffect is triggered.
When function is triggered, it add new eventListeners to the same element.